# Different Aspect Ratios: Notes vs. Slides

Tags: beamer, presentations

I created a presentation using LaTeX Beamer and I'd like to present it using [SplitShow](https://github.com/mpflanzer/splitshow).

Using an embedded `.nav` file in my PDF, I can use SplitShow's `interleaved` mode to display the slides on the projector and the notes on my laptop's display.

As the projector has a default resolution of 1024x768 (aspect ratio 4:3) and the laptop has 1680x1050 (16:10), I'd like to know if it's possible to have different aspect ratios for slides and notes (so they can be fullscreen on each screen).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: related https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/40